# negative percentage color condition in cross table

Tags: colors, crosstab, spotfire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLKor.png)I used cross table . in cross table i try to apply color condition on percentage column with the help of Color scheme grouping  option in cross table color property.

cross table -->color -->Color Scheme grouping -->Percentage.

here i appy fixed color mode and Addrule(percentage>25% with "GREEN" color), i took another Addrule(Percentage<25% with "RED" color)

now i am geeting wrong color code as like attachment.

for negative percentage -73% it should in "RED" color as per my condition.

how to over come this issue .

i would like to show percentage>25% in "GREEN" and percentage<25%(with negative values) in "RED" color.

Comment: could you please 1) provide sample data and 2) a screenshot of the behavior you're seeing in Spotfire?

Answer (score 0):

If the value axis of your crosstable is the percentage, then you can get the behavior you are looking for by entering a rule in the coloring of the crosstable like:

[Axis.Color]<.25

The rule should be entered under the percentage color scheme grouping.